# Need help solving what should probably be a very simple PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Trying to teach myself PDEs, and I'm stumped on what should probably be a very simple exercise:

Solve the equation $3u_{y}+u_{xy}=0$. And I am given the hint to let $v=u_{y}$ (it's a problem from Strauss' intro book).

Now, when you make the suggested substitution, $3u_{y}+u_{xy}=0$ becomes $3v+v_{x}=0$. The only problem is, I don't know how to solve this kind of PDE; the only types of PDE the book has really talked about at this point are ones of the form $au_{x}+bu_{y}=0$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants, and ones of the form $u_{x}+yu_{y}=0$.

What I've tried to do, therefore, is rewrite $v_{x}$ as $\frac{dv}{dx}$, subtract $3v$ from both sides, and turn it into a type of separable ODE type thing. Then, if I do that, and after substituting $v=u_{y}$ back in, I wind up getting that $u_{y}=\exp{(-3x)}\exp{(f(y))}$ Then, I suppose I'd have to integrate both sides with respect to $y$ to get the solution, but I'm worried it will take some messy integration by parts that never stops, and so I think that this method couldn't possibly be right.

Could somebody tell me the RIGHT way to do this problem? Thanks!! :)

Comment: Since you eliminated $y$ for $3v + v_x = 0$, you can treat it as $y_x + 3y = 0$.  Use method of constant coefficients.  I will post the answer as long as there are no users who post the best answers.

Comment: You mean the method of undetermined coefficients?

Comment: Method of constant coefficients.  That is: Set $y = e^{rx}$ where $r$ is any constant.  Evaluate the ODE by substitution and algebra.

Comment: Gotcha. Will try.

Comment: Yeah, it's still not working. Anyway, isn't that method only for inhomogeneous equations? Doesn't help me. If I try to get just the homogeneous part, I end up with $C\exp{(-3x)}$, which is exactly the same thing I got before, except that my constant was a constant function, $\exp{(f(y)}$, call it $g(y)$. So, I have that $u_{y}=g(y)\exp{(-3x)}$ - how do I go from that to give me an expression for $u(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that

$$3u_y + u_{xy} = 0$$

As the hints suggest, we use the substitution: $v = u_y$.  Then, as you said before, the new ODE is

$$3v + v_x = 0$$

By the method of constant coefficients, setting $v = e^{rx}$, we have...

$$\begin{aligned}
re^{rx} + 3e^{rx} &= 0\\
r + 3 &= 0\\
r &= -3
\end{aligned}$$

So we have

$$v(x) = c_1e^{-3x}$$

where $c_1$ is any constant.  But since $v = u_y$,

$$u_y(x,y) = c_1e^{-3x}$$

which implies that a solution is

$$u(x,y) = c_1ye^{-3x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note.
$$
3u_y+u_{xy}=0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(3u+u_x)=0
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad 3u(x,y)+u_x(x,y)=f(x),
$$
for some function $f=f(x)$. Next
$$
\mathrm{e}^{3x}\big(3u(x,y)+u_x(x,y)\big)=\mathrm{e}^{3x}f(x)
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \big(\mathrm{e}^{3x}u(x,y)\big)_x =\mathrm{e}^{3x}f(x),
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\mathrm{e}^{3x}u(x,y) =u(0,y)+\int_0^x \mathrm{e}^{3t}f(t)\,dt,
$$
or
$$
u(x,y) =\mathrm{e}^{-3x}\,u(0,y)+\int_0^x \mathrm{e}^{-3(x-t)}f(t)\,dt,
$$
for a function $f$ which can be determined from the initial data.